# Баг в полях ввода

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте. Вопрос таков: почему при нажатии на одну из форм, она не нажимается, а перекидывает на самую верхнюю?

```
<form action="file2.php" method="post" name="form1">
  Имя:
  <br />
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <br />
  Фамилия:
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
  <br />
  Отчество:
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="otchestvo" id="otchestvo" />
  <br />
  Страна:
  <br />
  <select name="country" id="country">
  <option>Казахстан</option>
  <option>Киргизстан</option>
  <option>Узбекистан</option>
  <option>Россия</option>
  <option>Китай</option>
  <option>Иран</option>
  </select>
  </label>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: А у тебя никаких скриптов на странице нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, проблема заключается в тегах `<label></label>`. Попробуйте так:

```
<form action="file2.php" method="post" name="form1"> 
<label>Имя: 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></label>
<label>Фамилия: 
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/></label> 
<label>Отчество: 
<input type="text" name="otchestvo" id="otchestvo"/></label> 
<label>Страна: 
<select name="country" id="country"> 
<option>Казахстан</option> 
<option>Киргизстан</option> 
<option>Узбекистан</option>
<option>Россия</option>
<option>Китай</option>
<option>Иран</option>
</select> </label> </form>
```

Хотя у меня именно этот ваш отрывок кода работает... Поищите, возможно, ошибка не в нем. Может где-то функция явы, или еще что ...

Comment: спасибо помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Где-то в коде стоит проверка на содержимое верхнего поля. Посмотрите атрибуты onclick и onfocus текстовых полей. Плюс, посмотрите javascript, навешивающий эти события на текстовые поля.

**Обновлено**
Ответил слишком поспешно. Читайте ответ @Дарика (уберите label). =)